What does Sri Ramayanam Bala Kanda say about lakshanas of people in Ayodhya?
How were the people in Ayodhya? Were they rich or poor? What were their daily activities?

Lakshanas of citizens of Ayodhya are mentioned in 6th chapter of Bala Khanda of Ramayana.

The people living in that excellent city were happy, virtuous, well
read (in the Vedas and the sastras) and content with the possessions
of their own. They were free from avarice. And always spoke the
truth.(6)

The below verses indicate all had sufficient wealth:

In that best of cities, there was not even a single householder who
had not adequate wealth or who had not achieved dharma, artha and kama
or who did not possess the wealth of foodgrains, cattle and horses.(7)
The lustful, the miserly, the unscholarly and atheists were not to be
seen anywhere in the city of Ayodhya.(8)
All men and women (in the city) were of righteous conduct, fully
self controlled and prosperous with good conduct and behaviour. They
were pure like maharshis.(9)
In the city, there was none without ear ornaments, without coronet,
without wearing garlands and none unclean. And none without the
anointment of fragrant on the body.(10)
(In the city of Ayodhya) there was no one who did not eat food to full
satisfaction and was not charitable. None was found without wearing
ornaments on the hands and bracelets on the upper arms and around the
neck. Also no one could be seen who had not restrained his passions
and emotions.(11)

The below verse says all used to perform sacrifices (without caste restrictions)

In the city of Ayodhya there was none who did not kindle the
sacrificial fire.There was none who did not perform a sacrifice.
There were no thieves or mean minded persons or persons of improper
descent of mixed castes.(12)
That time there was no atheist, no liar and none ignorant of the
sastras. There was no one who was jealous, incompetent or
illiterate.(14)

The below highlighted words also indicate that all castes in those days used to learn Vedas and Sastras in addition to being wealthy:

There was none who was not well versed in the Vedangas or who
did not perform religious vows. There was not even one who would not
donate in thousands. There was no one distracted or depressed.(15)
In Ayodhya, there was no man or woman who was not endowed with wealth
or beauty. It was not possible to see any one who had no devotion for
the king.(16)

All Varnas used to do their respective prescribed duties:

The brahmins were always interested in the performance of their
duties. They had control over their senses. They were charitable and
studious. They were selfcontrolled while accepting charity and
maintaining marital relations. (13)


There in Ayodhya the best of cities, the first of the four castes
(brahmins) used to worship gods and guests. They had the sense of
gratitude. They were munificient, heroic and possessed prowess. They
lived long. They were righteous and truthful. And they lived together
with their sons, grandsons and wives.(17 & 18)
The kshatriyas were obedient to brahmins and vaisyas followed
kshatriyas. Sudras assisted the three castes and all were fully
occupied in their respective professions.(19)


Beautiful answer. Thanks.
